# convert absolute form into linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

I would like to convert this problem into a Linear Programming Problem :

$\min |x|+|y|+|z|$

subject to $x+y \leq 1$

$2x+z=3$.

The solution to this problem is given [chapter](https://www.calvin.edu/~pribeiro/courses/Power%20Systems%20Interim/Sakis-Book/PSA_Appendix_B.pdf) and [here](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.in/2012/07/modeling-absolute-values.html). But I still do not get it. Could anyone please explain it explicitly the problem solution. Especially the part how the objective value is formed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's call the following model model $A$:

$\min |x|+|y|+|z|$

subject to $x+y \leq 1$

$2x+z=3$.

and the following model model $B$:

$\min x_1+x_2+|y|+|z|$

subject to $x_1-x_2+y \leq 1$

$2x_1-2x_2+z=3$.

$x_1,x_2 \geq 0$

I claim that the two models are equivalent.

To see this, suppose the optimal solution from  model $A$ that is  $(x_A, y_A, z_A)$. We can let

$$(x_{1B},x_{2B},y_B,z_B)=\begin{cases} (x_A,0,y_A,z_A)& x_A\geq0 \\ (0,-x_A,y_A,z_A)& x_A <0\end{cases}$$

and we can see that it is feasible for model $B$ and obtain the same value. Hence the optimal value for model $B$ cannot be worse than model $A$. the question is can it do better?

To verify that this is not the case, suppose we have an optimal solution for model $B$. $(x_{1B},x_{2B},y_B,z_B)$, we want to construct a solution to model $A$ that shares the same value.

I claim that $x_{1B}x_{2B}=0$, i.e., one of them is zero. Otherwise, we can construct another feasible solution $(x_{1B}-\min(x_{1B},x_{2B}),x_{2B}-\min(x_{1B},x_{2B}),y_B,z_B)$ that is feasible and has a smaller objective value, contradicting optimality of $(x_{1B},x_{2B},y_B,z_B)$.

Now, we can verify that

$$(x_A,y_A,z_A)=(x_{1B}-x_{2B},y_B,z_B)$$
is indeed feasible for model $A$.

If $x_{1B}=0$, then $x_A=x_{1B}-x_{2B}=-x_{2B}$, and $$|x_A|=-(-x_{2B})=x_{2B}=0+x_{2B}=x_{1B}+x_{2B}$$

If $x_{2B}=0$, then $x_A=x_{1B}-x_{2B}=x_{1B}$, and $$|x_A|=x_{1B}=x_{1B}+0=x_{1B}+x_{2B}$$

and hence the two optimization problem is equivalent.

To answer your original problem, repeat the same procedure for $y$ and $z$.

Comment: How is $(0,-x_A,y_A,z_A)$ a solution for the system B as clearly it violates the constraint $x2 \geq 0$

Comment: $x_A<0$, hence $x_{2B}=-x_A>0$